# Unable to unzip a file with the ubuntu terminal

Tags: unzip

I have got the following error message. The zip file(5GB) may be too big

```
Archive:  /home/wing92518/Documents/simulation_set_1_result/replication_1.zip
warning [/home/wing92518/Documents/simulation_set_1_result/replication_1.zip]:  849850736 extra bytes at beginning or within zipfile
  (attempting to process anyway)
error [/home/wing92518/Documents/simulation_set_1_result/replication_1.zip]:  start of central directory not found;
  zipfile corrupt.
  (please check that you have transferred or created the zipfile in the
  appropriate BINARY mode and that you have compiled UnZip properly)
```

Comment: 1) do you have enough free space?
2) attach the output of the command`file /home/wing92518/Documents/simulation_set_1_result/replication_1.zip`

Comment: Are you sure the zip downloaded properly? It says `zipfile corrupt.`

Comment: Yep, probably your file is corrupt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As your zip file seems to be corrupt (`zipfile corrupt`), you can try to repair the file and then unzip the repaired file:

```
zip -FF corrupt.zip --out repaired.zip
unzip repaired.zip
```

Note that the corrupt parts might be missing.

from unzip manual:

```
-FF
   --fixfix
          Fix the zip archive. The -F option can be used if some portions of the archive are missing, but requires a reasonably intact central directory.  The input archive is scanned as usual, but zip
          will ignore some problems.  The resulting archive should be valid, but any inconsistent entries will be left out.

          When  doubled  as  in -FF, the archive is scanned from the beginning and zip scans for special signatures to identify the limits between the archive members. The single -F is more reliable if
          the archive is not too much damaged, so try this option first.
```

([via](https://superuser.com/questions/23290/terminal-tool-linux-for-repair-corrupted-zip-files))